# Unable to extend nested struct in separate file

Tags: swift

I have two files,

**Parent.swift**

```
enum Parent {
    ...
}
```

**Child.swift**

```
extension Parent {
    struct Child {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I can use child like so

```
let child = Parent.Child()
```

However I cannot figure out how to write a extension for Child in a **separate file**.

**Child+Extension.swift**

```
extension Parent.Child {
    ...
}
```

I get the following error,

> 'Child' is not a memeber type of 'Parent'

Is this possible with the separate files? I know it will work if I combine parent.swift and child.swift.

Comment: This is an infamous bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-631

Comment: bummer, thanks for linking that. I was having a hard time coming up with a search query for this question

Comment: As said in the bug report comments, you may be able to workaround this by changing the order of the files in the "Compile Sources" build phase, for example, put "Child+Extension.swift" after "Child.swift".

Comment: I'll play around with this a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Hamish for the answer here,

This is a swift compiler bug as seen here, [bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-631](http://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-631)

A work around is to manually modify your "compile sources" making sure "Child+Extension.swift" is AFTER "Child.swift"